# Display an ion-item in an ion-list dynamically

Tags: ionic-framework, angularjs-ng-repeat, google-cloud-firestore, ion-list

I would like to display an ion-list with an ion-item-divider and ion-item. The ion-item is depending on ion-item-divider result.

So, this is my code:

```
<ion-list *ngFor="let group of groups">
<ion-item-divider>
    {{ group.name }}
</ion-item-divider>
<ion-item ng-repeat="company in loadCompanies(group.id)">
    <ion-avatar item-start>
        <img src="img/avatar.png">
    </ion-avatar>
    <h2>{{ company.name }}</h2>
    <p>Text example...</p>
</ion-item>
```

The ng-repeat is executing the loadCompanies function indefinitely... Do you have some tips to display the name of the company depending on the group id ..?

Comment: can you have a nested array for companies in your `groups` array, and use another `ngFor` for companies? ng-repeat is not going to stop because loadCompanies() always return something

Comment: Yes I can ! But I would like to call the loadCompanies function only when it's group is loaded... like an infinite scroll